# JNDI lookup hangs in HornetQ queue example

Tags: rmi, jndi, hornetq

I am trying to run the HornetQ jms/queue example with the JNDI and HornetQ server being hosted remotely.

The HornetQ server is running on 10.0.10.102.  The client running on 10.0.2.62.  Both the server and client machines are Linux boxes.

I configured the client-jndi.properties file on the client side as follows:
    `java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory`
    `java.naming.provider.url=jnp://10.0.10.102:1099`
    `java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces`

I configured the JNDI settings in the hornetq-beans.xml config file as follows:

```
<bean name="JNDIServer" class="org.jnp.server.Main">
  <property name="namingInfo">
     <inject bean="Naming"/>
  </property>
  <property name="port">1099</property>
  <property name="bindAddress">10.0.10.102</property>
  <property name="rmiPort">1098</property>
  <property name="rmiBindAddress">10.0.10.102</property>
</bean>
```

I get either a "Connection Refused" error or the client hangs looking up the JNDI service depending upon whether I ran the "rmiregistry" on the server side Linux machine (10.0.10.102).

Without running "rmiregistry", I get the following error on the client side:

```
 [java] javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: 10.0.10.102:30199 and discovery failed with error: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out] [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server /10.0.10.102:30199 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server /10.0.10.102:30199 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]]]
```

When I do run "rmiregistry" on the server host, the JNDI lookup hangs:

```
 [java] Jan 12, 2012 2:23:47 PM org.hornetq.common.example.HornetQExample getContext
 [java] INFO: using server0/client-jndi.properties for jndi
```

Hangs here...

Any idea what else I need to do to configure JNDI or my Java environment for the JNDI lookup process?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That example was written to be executed on the same terminal. The example is starting a remote server and the local server on the same box.

As you're running it remotely, you're creating some mechanism to start a remote server, so you're probably messing up some config.

I don't have enough information as to how you are starting the server, so I can't really answer your question right now. I will try to help you if you provide more information on how you're starting the server and what configuration changes are you making.

I would recommend you to read the Netty/remoting configuration chapter of HornetQ.

As for Netty here I just think you're changing the wrong file since

Comment: Ok, I will read the Netty/remoting configuration of HornetQ.  I had read it once, but maybe I overlooked something.